# Pass delegate with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I have a class, which has a method taking a delegate parameter and it is to be invoked with reflection, e.g.:

```
namespace NSa
{
    public delegate void dlg(string p1, string p2);

    public class dyn
    {
        void method(dlg d)
        {
            // call d...
        }
    }
}
```

In another class I need to call `dyn.method` with reflection:

```
namespace NSa
{
    public delegate void dlg(string p1, string p2);

    public void fun(string a, string b) { Console.Write(a); }

    public class other
    {
        void caller_method()
        {
            dlg x = fun;

            //... 

            var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile("xx.dll");
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags flags = (System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
            System.Reflection.Module[] dynModules = assembly.GetModules();
            Type dynType = dynModules[0].GetType("NSa.dyn");
            object dynObj = Activator.CreateInstance(dynType);               
            System.Reflection.MethodInfo dynMethod = dynType.GetMethods(flags).Where(m => m.Name == "method").First();
            dynMethod.Invoke(dynObj, new object[] {x});             
        }
    }
}
```

I get exception:

```
Object of type 'NSa.dlg' cannot be converted to type 'NSa.dlg'.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: One bit of advice for future questions - code is a lot easier to read if it follows normal naming convention for the language in question, avoids abbreviations, and uses `using` directives instead of fully-qualifying every type name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're declaring the same type twice in two different assemblies. Those will be two completely different types as far as the CLR is concerned, which no conversion between them.

You should be using the delegate declared in the same assembly as `dyn`, in order to pass it to `dyn.method`. If you don't know about that assembly at compile-time, you'll need to create an instance of the method using [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.createdelegate.aspx).

I'd also suggest that by using different namespace declarations for different assemblies, it would be easier to tell which type came from which assembly.

Comment: Right. How to create an instance of a delegate type in the first assembly that points to a function (fun in the example) in the caller assembly?

Comment: @paulsimmons: As I said, you use `Delegate.CreateDelegate`, passing in a `MethodInfo` and a target reference. I'd give an example, but your current code wouldn't even compile as `fun` isn't in a type...

Comment: oops, i did not see that before the edit, thanks! it solved my problem.